# Windows 10 Start Menu Using Generic Icon for Programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, start-menu, cache

Occasionally I have seen Windows 10 use a generic icon in the start menu for every program:

[image]

but it should look like this:

[image]

I have not been able to determine the cause for this happening. It has happened on two of my machines now inexplicably. Neither of them started this way, but after a few months of use they ended up this way.

Any idea what has happened and how to correct it? This is Windows 10 21H2 (19044).

Comment: It has happened on two of my machines now ..... No such thing here at any time. Do you some non-compliant software installed?

Comment: @John these are personal desktops of mine

Comment: My machines are my own as well.

Comment: @John, so what is there to comply with?

Comment: I would try a quick `sfc /scannow` to see if anything comes up.  The next thing I would try is killing `explorer.exe` and deleting all icon cache files (`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*.db` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%\IconCache.db`), then rebooting.  Background programs might still be using some of the iconcache*.db files, so it's possible you may need to delete the cache files offline (use a Windows install USB or Hirens, etc).

Comment: so what is there to comply with? –   ....  I am not certain except this is an error I have never seen on a properly operating Windows 10 machine. And you have this issue on more than one machine.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to rebuild the icon cache as suggested by Paul Pi.. , reboot and see how it goes.  It is simple and you have nothing to lose.  I have yet in all of my years seen SFC fix anything.  I am not saying it doesn't work.. just that it has never helped me in the 100s of times I have tried to use it.

Comment: I've noticed this too but after a few seconds it does generate the correct icons. Does this not happen for you after waiting? Also, it would be worth searching in the start menu "Adjust the appearance and performance of windows", and then make sure "Adjust for best appearance" is selected in the resulting window.